# Python Threading for Port Scanning

Tags: python-multithreading

I intended to scan my LAN to discover open services.
I created a Python script to sweep all IP:Port combinations. The first try was based on a for loop and in took ages for this to complete.

Then I start reading about threading and improved it a little bit. Nevertheless it is still taking almost 200 seconds to sweep 10 IP addresses. I was hoping to get the results within seconds because I thought that I will start 10 x 65525 scans simultaneously and they will response or timeout in 1 second.

How could I improve the performance and speed?

```
import socket
import threading

class Portscan(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
    def run(self):
        #print("trying {}:{}" .format(self.ip, self.port))
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.settimeout(1)
            sock.connect((self.ip, self.port))
            open_sockets.append("{}:{} is open" .format(self.ip, self.port))
            return True
        except:
            return False

open_sockets = []
target_ips = ["192.168.1.{}" .format(i) for i in range(1,11)]
target_ports = range(1,65526)

scan_list = []
for ip in target_ips:
    for port in target_ports:
        scan = Portscan(ip, port)
        scan_list.append(scan)

for scan in scan_list:
    scan.start()

for scan in scan_list:
    scan.join()

print(open_sockets)
```

Comment: Creating a thread for every single scan is expensive. You'd be better off using the pool `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`, initializing it with ~500-1000 threads, then giving jobs to it. Then just make your current `run` method a standalone function, and give it to the pool to run. Idk if that's your main issue, but threads are expensive to create/destroy.

Comment: Also, you never close the sockets, so you may be facing resource exhaustion too.

Comment: And, while the GIL doesn't directly affect I/O tasks, the creation of sockets/threads are expensive and require the CPU, so you can't actually create all the sockets/threads "at once". You can create one at a time, just quickly. I [cleaned up your code a bit](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/1fb81f3e602d87d249df5baaffe78662). This takes ~10 seconds/host by using 10,000 threads.

Comment: Many thanks for the hints. Closing the socket improved things only for 0.5 seconds in my script. I also tested your code and it took 72 seconds vs 187 seconds of original script. Quite an improvement.

Comment: @Carcigenicate
I tried with below code but it took still around 180 secs. You code runs in 72 secs. Shoudn't the results be similar?  
`with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10000) as executor:  
        [executor.submit(portscan,ip , port) for ip in target_ips for port in target_ports]`

Comment: I'd need to play with it when I get home. I don't think I've ever used a `ThreadPoolExecutor` before. You're a suing list comprehensions there though, since I'm assuming `submit` doesn't return the computed value (since if it did, jobs would be submitted synchronously, which would be bad). Since you're using a comprehension, a massive list, 600,000 element list is being created in the background, which eats memory, and requires processing by the CPU (which will directly compete with your scanner threads).

Comment: Unless `submit` returns a `Future`, which I guess given the module, is likely. I'll need to read the docs when I get home.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] so I can reproduce it?

Comment: https://snippi.com/s/scdedng
https://snippi.com/s/d4cbtpa
I googled multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool and did not find much documentation about its usage. It seems to be a hidden module.

Comment: `ThreadPool` has the same documentation as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. It's the same interface, just using threads instead of processes. Yes, it would be nice if it were documented though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to run it and do comparisons. Some notes though about the linked code: 1. Don't mutate objects between threads. For lists, this happens to be safe because list appends are atomic, but it is not a good habit. Use methods that return returns like `map` like I used, or make use of the `Future`s that `submit` returns. Mutating objects across threads is bad unless you're careful. 2. As I mentioned before, don't use a list comprehension there. List comprehensions create new lists. You're abusing them there to loop, and are creating a massing, ~650,000 element list in

Comment: the process, which takes up memory and CPU time. 3. **Never** use a bare `except:`. Like I had, specify what *precise* error you want to catch. Catching all errors just hides bugs and will bite you.